# How do I permanently display the Contacts folder (in the Folder Pane) from my .pst file?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I am running Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2019, 64-bit version on Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit OS.

I have a local `.pst` file where I store my contacts, and a single email account linked in from my ISP. The Folder Pane is always showing.

In order to see the Contracts folder within the `.pst` file, I have to click on the ellipsis at the bottom of the Folder Pane. Then choose Folders. The choices in addition to the … are Mail, Calendar, People, and Tasks. I have no favorites set up.

If I have the `.pst` Contacts folder open, click the calendar icon at the bottom of the Folder Pane, work with the calendar, click the envelope icon at the bottom of the Folder Pane, the `.pst` Contacts folder disappears when I return to seeing my email messages.

How do I permanently display the Contacts folder (in the Folder Pane) from my `.pst` file?

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook, open the ellipses (...) and select Navigation Options.

Then in the sub window that comes up, move People UP and something else down.

I have People third in the list and it always shows.

You can also select the number of items to show. 4 is fine for me with the main icons always showing.

If you want Contacts in the folder tree, you must use Favorites.

Mail, Calendar, and Contacts are really Views and using the lower left Navigation pane works best for me overall.

[image: Outlook Navigation Options.]

Comment: Thank you for confirming my suspicion.  "If you want Contacts in the folder tree, you must use Favorites."  I have hundreds of contacts in a custom hiarchy.  Funny that other users would not want to see this folder all the time.

Comment: You may wish to accept my answer as it has confirmed for you.

Answer (score -1):

You can customize how the buttons at the bottom of the Navigation pane appear. For more information, see [Change the buttons on the Navigation Bar](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-what-appears-on-the-navigation-bar-83cf518b-6233-4706-a7bd-9045554c1b8b#__toc256681968).

Comment: All of the answer information must be here, in the answer. Links should be used for attribution and further research, but it should not be necessary to follow a link to get the answer.